# updating mysql database after an entry is deleted

Tags: php, mysql

Working on deleting an entry from my database table.

Currently the delete is working. However it deletes the "id + 1"

My script populates a "delete " button right next to an entry populated from mysql table.

When I hit delete next to an entry, it deletes the item +1.

I think it has to do with the while loop, the way I populate items.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
<?php 
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) : ?>
<tr>
  </table border = '1'><br><table border = '1'><th>Subject</th><th>Sender</th>    <th>Message</th><th>Delete</th>
  <?php 
  echo "<tr><td>";
  echo $row['subject'];
  echo "<td>";
   echo $row['sender'];
  echo "<td>";
  echo $row['msgText'];
  echo "<td>";
  ?>
    <form action="delete.php" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="delete_id" value="<?php  $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];   ?>" />
      <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
   </form>
</tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

here is the script in delete.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","something");
  $sql = "DELETE FROM `mailbox` WHERE `id`= '$id'";
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
   header('Location: loggedin.php');
?>
```

Comment: you seem to be setting the same session variable on every loop instance. What good does that do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="hidden" name="delete_id" value="<?php  $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];   ?>" />
```

change it to:

```
<input type="hidden" name="delete_id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
```

and in your delete.php, simply replace `$_SESSION['id']` to `$_POST['delete_id']`

P/S: By the way, you've forgot to add `session_start();` in your form's php, if you do really want to use it, but not a good idea for this time.

Answer (score 0):

The `$_SESSION['id']` gets overridden each time in the loop.

Why not just simply use `$_POST["delete_id"]` to retrieve row id.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Table Structure` is wrong

```
<?php 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) : 
?>

<tr>
    <th>Subject</th>
    <th>Sender</th>
    <th>Message</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<?php 
  echo "<td>";
  echo $row['subject'];
  echo "</td><td>";
   echo $row['sender'];
  echo "</td><td>";
  echo $row['msgText'];
  echo "</td>";
  ?>
  <td>
       <form action="delete.php" method="post">
           <input type="hidden" name="delete_id" value="<?php  $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];   ?>" />
           <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
       </form>
  </td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

also don't use `$_SESSION['id']` while deleting the records. use `$_POST['delete_id']`